# Why does the graph of the derivative not correspond to the graph of the function

Tags: математика, sympy

При помощи sympy получаю производную функции:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> x = sp.Symbol('x')
>>> f = -0.01 * sp.sin(0.05 * x - 0.7) + 0.01 * sp.sin(6.2 * x + 4.5)
>>> f.diff(x)
−0.0005cos(0.05−0.7)+0.062cos(6.2+4.5)
```

Строю графики функции и её производной:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100)
plt.plot(x, -0.01 * np.sin(0.05 * x - 0.7) + 0.01 * np.sin(6.2 * x + 4.5), 'b-')
plt.twinx()
plt.plot(x, -0.0005 * np.cos(0.05 * x - 0.7) + 0.062 * np.cos(6.2 * x + 4.5), 'g-')
plt.plot(plt.xlim(), [0, 0], 'k--')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не похоже, что те места, где производная равна нулю, являются экстремумом. Никак не пойму, почему.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the site of the Russian-speaking SO community, please translate your question into Russian.

Comment: Что-то очень уж смущает ваш график вообще. На таком диапазоне он явно выглядит [не так](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7B-0.01*Sin%5B0.05+x+-+0.7%5D+%2B+++++0.01*Sin%5B6.2*x+%2B+4.5%5D%2C+-0.0005*Cos%5B0.05+x+-+0.7%5D+%2B+++++0.062*Cos%5B6.2+x+%2B+4.5%5D%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+100%7D%5D).

Comment: Да вот именно, график функции np.sin(6.2) должен быть очень частым. Перезагружал ноутбук, пробовал другое виртуальное окружение - результат один и тот же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы поймали "интерференцию" функции синуса выбранного набора точек по x.
У вас интервал между точками равен 1. А период функции равен 6.2/(2*pi) = 0.98676...

Для правильного точки отображения, нужно чтобы на каждый период функции приходилось по несколько точек по x. Например, если увеличить частоту точек в 100 раз: `x = np.arange(100*100) *(1./100)` , получим:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А график выглядел таким гладким... Теперь все встало на свои места :-)